# json_decode() returns blank but it's valid json

Tags: php, json

```
$a = '[{"function":"error_handler","class":"LP","type":"::","args":[256,"Call to undefined method LP_pdo::get_rorzxx() on D:\\MARK\\htdocs\\lessphptest\\application\\controllers\\users.php (23)","D:\\MARK\\htdocs\\lessphp\\LP.php",210,{"e":{"type":1,"message":"Call to undefined method LP_pdo::get_rorzxx()","file":"D:\\MARK\\htdocs\\lessphptest\\application\\controllers\\users.php","line":23}}]},{"file":"D:\\MARK\\htdocs\\lessphp\\LP.php","line":210,"function":"trigger_error","args":["Call to undefined method LP_pdo::get_rorzxx() on D:\\MARK\\htdocs\\lessphptest\\application\\controllers\\users.php (23)",256]},{"function":"shutdown","class":"LP","type":"::","args":[]}]';
$a = json_decode($a);
print_r($a);

echo json_last_error();
```

`print_r()` returns blank.

`json_last_error()` returns 4 which is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

But, when I run the json string in http://jsonlint.com/ it returns `Valid JSON`

Any ideas why?

Comment: try: $b = array(); $b = json_decode($a,true); this should convert the json into an associative array, but you first gotta declare $b = array();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to escape your `\` once for PHP and once again for JSON

`D:\\\\....`

Comment: surely you mean escape your \ rather than /

Comment: that works, but is there a function that does that? I just find/replace in Notepad :-)

Comment: @IMB PHP has excellent find/replace capabilities, too!  `$str = str_replace('\', '\\', $str);` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set encoding to utf-8...did the job for me